Liferay 7.0 permissions of a web content in a page
I'm not a developer but I work on a site made with Liferay 7.0.
I need to find in a easy way (a query possibly because I'm good with Oracle db) the permissions related to a web content instantiated in any pages of a Liferay 7.0 site.
I know that the Web Content are saved in JOURNALARTICLE table with DDMSTRUCTUREKEY = 'BASIC-WEB-CONTENT' and I can get the related permissions with the RESOURCEPERMISSION table.
But I can not find the instantiated web content in a page (LAYOUT table) in the JOURNALARTICLE table and it's very difficult find the permissions in the modal (see image)  because my site has almost 1000 roles/teams
sample of permission management of web content in a page
Thank you!
I want to know if there's a way to get the permissions related to a web content like the one I have found using the tables.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
